# Check if date string in Y-m-d format falls in the current month

Tags: php, date

I want to only shows result for the current month, but I have no idea how to do this, my current output is like this.

**Output**

```
2014-04-11
-> array
2014-04-11 
2014-04-05
2014-03-29
```

**PHP**

```
$date = date('Y-m-d');

echo $date;

echo "<pre>";
foreach ($submissions as $test){
    if($date >=  substr($test['thing']['created'], 0, 10)){
        echo substr($test['thing']['created'], 0, 10);
        echo "<br>";
    }
}
echo "</pre>";
```

My current code wont work as its only checking if the whole number is greater or equal to, any ideas anyone?

Comment: You need to filter the data by date in the database.

Comment: This cant be done as its pulling data from an external source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try with [`strtotime`](http://php.net/strtotime):

```
$year  = date('Y');
$month = date('m');

foreach ($submissions as $test) {
  $timestamp = strtotime($test['thing']['created']);
  $testYear  = date('Y', $timestamp);
  $testMonth = date('m', $timestamp);

  if (($month >= $testMonth && $year == $testYear) || $year > $testYear) {
    // test passed
  }
}
```

Comment: This will only check if its greater or equal to that date, i need to only shows it its greater or equal to that month

Comment: no need to use timestamp here. He don't want to sort it.

Comment: @Apolo strtotime is not used for sorting.

Comment: yes but I mean, if you have dates in $test like 'Y-m-d', you just have to keep the 'Y-m' part and use a string comparison. Translation to timestamp is not very useful

Answer (score 1):

If your problem is to have only results of current month :

```
$date = date('Y-m');
echo "<pre>";
foreach ($submissions as $test){
    // if month & year is equal
    if($date == substr($test['thing']['created'], 0, 7)){
        echo substr($test['thing']['created'], 0, 10);
        echo "<br>";
    }
}
echo "</pre>";
```

If you want to sort it, you will have to convert to timestamp

Answer (score 0):

i'm not a pro in php but take a look here : https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.date.php

does date('m') would be a solution for your problem?

Comment: Nop , cause the month of 12 april 2001 and 05 April 2014 is the same

Answer (score 0):

You can try 2 ways :

- convert them to timestamp, then compare the int
- If you are taking the dates frome a DB, ORDER BY date in the query

Answer (score 0):

Variable for current month first `$cur_m=date('m')`

Explode your variable in loop with `-`.

```
$p = explode('-',$test['thing']['created']);
```

in loop check for current month like below

```
if($p[1]==$cur_m){ your code... }
```

Comment: For same Year, add same logic for Year also.